# How to update tray icon

Tags: javascript, electron

In `Electron`, it is possible to create a tray icon by using [`new Tray(image)`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md#new-trayimage), for example:

```
let iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png');
appIcon = new Tray(iconPath);
```

**As stated in the documentation:**

> **..**
>  Creates a new tray icon associated with the image. 
> **..**

**Is it possible to replace the current Tray icon, instead of creating a *new* one?**

Comment: The docs you link suggest you can set the image. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using the [`tray.setImage(image)`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md#traysetimageimage) function.

**Example:**

```
let iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png');
appIcon.setImage(iconPath);
```